# Add more than two tabBar options to storyboard

Tags: storyboard, tabbarcontroller

I am new to `storyboard`. My question is when add `UITabBarViewController` to storyboard then it set as default two tab options. Then how to add a third tab to `TabBar` without write code.  It is possible or not?

Comment: Refer the following link it will help you to achieve 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13820407/how-to-add-more-tabs-in-tab-view-controller-storyboard-application

Comment: Is that solved your problem?

Comment: Welcome If it helped up vote the comment so that it will help others.