# How to add tabs to a tabbed application on Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard, uitabbar

I have looked at tutorials, but none of them are for the latest version of `xcode`, the version I have.

They all explain how to do this in older versions, but some options they want just aren't there in the newer version. Also, older versions have multiple .xib files for each view, whereas the latest version has one .storyboard file for all the views.

So can anyone give me a detailed, easy to follow (because I am a new to app dev) guide on how to do this?

Comment: One video, the guy just dragged an item to the tab bar and it added a new tab, but that was probably in an older version of xcode.

Comment: Always tag your questions in as much near to your topic. like ios, iphone, etc

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 4.2 Tabbed Application - Adding New Tab view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952576/xcode-4-2-tabbed-application-adding-new-tab-view)

Answer (score 0):

[Xcode Tabbed Application - Adding New Tab view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952576/xcode-4-2-tabbed-application-adding-new-tab-view)
Hey, next time just search the web for it ;) but it's okay this time.