# Embed New ViewController Into Existing UITabBarController?

Tags: swift, uitabbar

I'm looking to create a persistent UIView that doesn't change when different tabs are selected.  Since I prefer to use IB, the simplest way seems to be creating a UIView inside a new ViewController and embedding it in the TabBarController.  I've tried using the "Embed In Tab Bar Controller", however that creates a new Tab Bar Controller and doesn't seem to provide an option to use my existing one.

Is there any way of accomplishing this? Embed in existing without starting over?

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Already answered, Please find your answer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7952576/4843725)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode Tabbed Application - Adding New Tab view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952576/xcode-tabbed-application-adding-new-tab-view)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'm not trying to add another tab view ViewController.  I'm instead looking to have a UIView (or container, or something else) stay in one spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a view to your TabBarController in storyboard by drag and drop an UIView on the menu of your TabBarController.

[image]

Then you just have to subclass your TabBarController and add this view to the main view of your TabBarController.

```
import UIKit

class CustomTabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

    @IBOutlet var alwaysOnView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(alwaysOnView)
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you get the View to drag and drop?  IB won't let me place it on the Custom Tab Bar Controller .

Comment: I've edited my answer with some markdown on the screenshot to make sure you get right the drag and drop process ;)

Comment: Thank you!  I wasn't aware of this technique; very helpful!

Comment: Quick follow-up: hat would be the easiest way to move the view?

Comment: I guess you mean "positioning the view" so the best solution I guess would be to add left right bottom and height constraints programmatically to the view.